# pivot tables using PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

**Is it possible to create pivot tables using PHPExcel or PHPSpreadsheet  .**

I have already tried exporting by templates but it doesn't work and the pivot table crashes .

*IN case of templates approach I have created a pivot table with data source as one sheet . Tried modifying the data sheet but pivot table crashes*

Any help is appreciated .

Thanks in advance